# How do I use countDistinct in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to aggregate a column in a Spark dataframe using Scala, like so:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

dfNew.agg(countDistinct("filtered"))
```

but I get the error:

```
 error: value agg is not a member of Unit
```

Can anyone explain why?

EDIT: to clarify what I am trying to do:
I have a column which is a string array, and I want to count the distinct elements over all the rows, not interested in any other columns. Data:

```
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|racist|filtered                                                                                                                                                      |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|false |[rt, @dope_promo:, crew, beat, high, scores, fugly, frog, , https://time.com/sxp3onz1w8]                                                                      |
|false |[rt, @axolrose:, yall, call, kermit, frog, lizard?, , https://time.com/wdaeaer1ay]                                                                                |
```

And I want to count filtered, giving:

```
rt:2, @dope_promo:1, crew:1, ...frog:2 etc
```

Comment: for aggregate function , you need to apply groupBy first. this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500816/how-to-use-countdistinct-in-scala-with-spark

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use countDistinct in Scala with Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500816/how-to-use-countdistinct-in-scala-with-spark)

Comment: OK maybe I am trying to use the wrong function. I have a column with is a string array, and I want to count the distinct elements over all the rows, not interested in any other columns. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: `dfNew.agg(countDistinct("filtered")).show(false)` should solve .

Comment: Thanks but same error.

Comment: you should share how you created the dataframe starting from data level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `explode` your array first before you can count occurences: to view the counts of each element:

```
dfNew
.withColumn("filtered",explode($"filtered"))
.groupBy($"filtered")
.count
.orderBy($"count".desc)
.show
```

or just to get the count of distinct elements :

```
val count = dfNew
.withColumn("filtered",explode($"filtered"))
.select($"filtered")
.distinct
.count
```