# countDistinct - value not found error in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I started learning spark and I am getting an error attached in the below snapshot, please let me know the modification needed to be done

attached the image containing code and error info

[image: attached the image containing code and error info]

Comment: function countDistinct is not in scope, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500816/how-to-use-countdistinct-in-scala-with-spark

Answer (score 1):

You need to import that function with

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct
```

Comment: Great, if it helped you, accepting the answer would be appreciated!